# PC: Top Gun Hard Lock crashes on startup when a 360 controller is plugged in

Tags: windows, crash, dll, game-controller

I just bought yesterday the PC version of Top Gun Hard Lock (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Top-Gun-Hard-Lock-Windows/dp/B006T9L4GA/) and I was reading online that it natively supports 360 controllers. The problem I'm having is that I've got 3 different 360 controllers and with all of them, if I launch "C:\Program Files (x86)\TopGun - Hardlock\binary\TopGun.exe (4626 KB)" **whilst a controller is plugged in** then I get a spinning icon for 1 second and then the game crashes with the message:

```
"TopGun.exe has stopped working", and the game exits.
```

If I unplugged the controller then the game works fine.

I am currently using Windows 10 64bits and those controllers work fine with every other game. And the drivers are correctly installed in Windows, as there are not conflicts or errors under Device manager tool.

I've checked the event viewer and this are the entries about the failure there. I tried reinstalling the game and 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package' but the issue is still present:

***ERROR:***

```
Faulting application name: TopGun.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f50f310
Faulting module name: MSVCR90.dll, version: 9.0.30729.9279, time stamp: 0x57fb316a
Exception code: 0xc0000417
Fault offset: 0x0006ccd5
Faulting process id: 0x279c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d32c1ae3ca9be2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\TopGun - Hardlock\binary\TopGun.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9279_none_50939ec6bcb7c97c\MSVCR90.dll
Report Id: 33a2b452-274b-45d7-ba80-530d21b90de0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

***INFORMATION***

```
Fault bucket 116305916428, type 5
Event Name: BEX
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: TopGun.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 4f50f310
P4: MSVCR90.dll
P5: 9.0.30729.9279
P6: 57fb316a
P7: 0006ccd5
P8: c0000417
P9: 00000000
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER87B1.tmp.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER87F1.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER8800.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER8810.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_TopGun.exe_1b7162aa9a4f1abde2a4ee88dc68aa691c9cfd5_65ab11ae_26d38e87

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 33a2b452-274b-45d7-ba80-530d21b90de0
Report Status: 268435457
Hashed bucket: 7f9881e639cd1d8a7dbaa7973d88689a
```

Could you please let me know what the solution for this problem could be? or if you need anything else from me, could you let me know please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Appears to be a software incompatibility with the Windows 10 Xbox 360 drivers

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a possible problems with the drivers. I've been doing quite a lot of tests during the last few hours, installing different versions of the drivers, different apps, etc... but still nothing. I think I'll play with keyboard for a little while...